# Visual studio 2013 properties window datasource

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datagridview, datasource

I'm having trouble selecting the datasource for a datagridview inside the properties window. It worked for the first seven datagridviews, but now suddenly, an error message pops up every time I click the dropdown sign:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object.

After restarting visual studio and trying again, an error message pops up:

> Root element is missing.

On the second try the drop down menu works and I can choose an object, but after choosing an warning message pops up:

> Property value is not valid.

details:

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.PropertyManager' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager'.

After that it throws the first error message again every time I click the datasource dropdown menu. It does so for every datasource property in the entire solution.

I hope somebody can help me.

I even tried reinstalling visual studio.

All the Code:

MainForm.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Database;

namespace MainProject
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MainProject
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
    }
}
```

MainForm.Designer.cs is to big to add here.

Comment: Hard to help you if you don't include some code...

Comment: There is no code, i only used the designer until this point.

Comment: In Visual Studio, there is a tab to switch between designer and code views.  Switch to code view and paste the code here.

Comment: I added all the code i could, but I don't think the problem is with the code.

Comment: Have you tried to remove some datagridviews to see if that solve the problem? There might be some conflict for some reason.

Comment: I did try that, but it didn't help. The problem is solved now although I don't know how!